# Running three python scripts at the same time in a C# application

Tags: python, c#, sockets, ip, port

I want to run three python scripts that receives images and Json files from a client through different ports using socket programming in a C# application. I run these scripts as three separate processes in C#.

The processes serveri.py and serjson5.py receive images and Json files respectively at the same time. When serveri.py starts receiving images on port 5501, the process executing serjson5.py stops and the port 5502 closes. Why does this happen?

Here are the codes for all the files. serjson20.py is similar to serjson5.py with different save_folder and port(5500).

**C# code:**

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
            {
                // Execute the Python scripts with the IP address as a command-line argument
                string script1Path = "serveri.py";
                string script2Path = "serjson20.py";
                string script3Path = "serjson5.py";
                string arguments = ipAddress;

                Process process1 = new Process();
                process1.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
                process1.StartInfo.Arguments = $"{script1Path} {arguments}";
                process1.Start();

                Process process2 = new Process();
                process2.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
                process2.StartInfo.Arguments = $"{script2Path} {arguments}";
                process2.Start();

                Process process3 = new Process();
                process3.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
                process3.StartInfo.Arguments = $"{script3Path} {arguments}";
                process3.Start();
            }
```

**serveri.py**

```
import socket
import struct
import os
import sys
import threading

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    server_ip = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print("Error: Server IP address is missing.")
    sys.exit(1)

def receive_image(client_socket, save_folder):
    # Receive the size of the image
    size_data = client_socket.recv(4)
    image_size = struct.unpack("!I", size_data)[0]

    # Receive the image data
    image_data = b""
    while len(image_data) < image_size:
        data = client_socket.recv(image_size - len(image_data))
        if not data:
            break
        image_data += data

    if len(image_data) == image_size:
        # Get the original image name from the client
        image_name = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        print(image_name)
        # Save the received image
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, image_name)
        with open(save_path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(image_data)
        print(f"Image received and saved as {save_path}")
    else:
        print("Incomplete image data received")

def start_server(server_ip):
    # Create a TCP socket
    server_port = 5501
    save_folder = "chche"
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        # Bind the socket to the server IP and port
        server_socket.bind((server_ip, server_port))
        print(f"Server started on {server_ip}:{server_port}")

        # Listen for incoming connections
        server_socket.listen(1)

        while True:
            # Accept a client connection
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
            print(f"Accepted connection from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")

            # Receive the image from the client
            receive_image(client_socket, save_folder)

            # Close the client connection
            client_socket.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
    finally:
        # Close the server socket
        server_socket.close()
        print("Server stopped")

start_server(server_ip)
```

**serjson5.py**

```
import socket
import struct
import os
import sys
import threading

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    server_ip = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print("Error: Server IP address is missing.")
    sys.exit(1)

def receive_json(client_socket, save_folder):
    # Receive the size of the json
    size_data = client_socket.recv(4)
    json_size = struct.unpack("!I", size_data)[0]

    # Receive the json data
    json_data = b""
    while len(json_data) < json_size:
        data = client_socket.recv(json_size - len(json_data))
        if not data:
            break
        json_data += data

    if len(json_data) == json_size:
        # Get the original json name from the client
        json_name = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()

        # Save the received json
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, json_name)
        #save_path = f"{save_folder}/json_name"
        with open(save_path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(json_data)
        print(f"Json received and saved as {save_path}")
    else:
        print("Incomplete Json data received")

def start_server(server_ip):
    # Create a TCP socket
    server_port = 5502
    save_folder = "chche"
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        # Bind the socket to the server IP and port
        server_socket.bind((server_ip, server_port))
        print(f"Server started on {server_ip}:{server_port}")

        # Listen for incoming connections
        server_socket.listen(1)

        while True:
            # Accept a client connection
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
            print(f"Accepted connection from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")

            # Receive the image from the client
            receive_json(client_socket, save_folder)

            # Close the client connection
            client_socket.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
    finally:
        # Close the server socket
        server_socket.close()
        print("Server stopped")

start_server(server_ip)
```

Comment: Change from : def start_server(server_ip) to : def start_server(server_ip, server_port) and remove server_port = 5502

Comment: @jdweng Will try passing port number as an argument to the function. But Can I know what difference if it would make ?